# how can create wallet for use in substrate?

Tags: polkadot, pallet

> i need create wallet for user in substrate pallet .

for example i need create wallet for user and return the wallet info for user also use can use that info for transfer money to other wallets .

**now i need to know what should i do for that ?**

actually i need create wallet for user programmatically .

Comment: you don't create a wallet inside a pallet, that is a misconception... you should read more on the substrate architecture

Comment: Please provide some context and an example of what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/ - subkey generate will show you how to create a private key. As demonstrated by recent solana hacks it would be a very bad idea to log the private seed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

*Opinion: It's almost always a bad idea to manage keys for users directly and by default. This is anti-ethos in Web3.*

There are plenty of suggestions to start listed here for *users* to create wallets: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-wallets

Checkout https://polkadot.network/blog/introducing-polkadot-kusama-gifts/ - this tool can be used to allow users to claim assets into a wallet they create. Source: https://github.com/hamidra/dotdrop

Also worth a read to understand how you might manage a more complicated accounting setup: https://www.parity.io/blog/building-a-hot-wallet-with-substrate-primitives/